# Display data bound from a Controller in a modal with AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, modal-dialog, angularjs-scope

I am simply trying to display data in a bootstrap modal once a button is clicked however the data is just not showing.

Controller:

```
var MainCtrl = function ($scope) {
$scope.vlad = {};

$scope.doModal = function() {
    $scope.vlad = {
        me: 'yep you',
        so: 'yes'
    }
}

}
```

HTML:

```
<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modal-1">
```

```
  <!-- Modal heading -->
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    <h3 class="modal-title">Modal</h3>
  </div>
  <!-- // Modal heading END -->
  <!-- Modal body -->
  <div class="modal-body">

  {{vlad.me}} and {{vlad.so}}

  </div>
  <!-- // Modal body END -->
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

However the data shows up fine on page, and the modal's code is within the container div where the angular controller is referenced.

Help please?

Comment: can we see this in plnkr? seems about right the way you are doing it.

Comment: Works fine in plnkr actually. I wonder what it can possibly be

Comment: I wonder if audience could see your plunker?

Comment: Are there any errors in console? Install angularjs plugin for chrome and try debug it.